# Can't parse a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I started learning node.js and I am facing an error. 
Here's the code:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) =>{ //request, response
    const pathName = req.url;

    if (pathName === '/' || pathName === '/overview'){
        res.end('This is the OVERVIEW') //  res trimite catre client, req trimite catre server
    } else if (pathName === '/product'){
        res.end('This is the PRODUCT');
    } else if (pathName === '/api') {

        fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data.json`, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            const productData = JSON.parse(data);
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
            response.end(data);
        });

    } else{
        res.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-type': 'text/html', 
            'my-own-header': 'hello-world'
        });
        res.end('<h1>This page could not be found!</h1>');
    }

    res.end('Hello from the server!');
});
```

the problem is in this if:

```
else if (pathName === '/api') {

        fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data.json`, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            const productData = JSON.parse(data);
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
            response.end(data);
        });
```

The error i get:

undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at ReadFileContext.callback (c:\Users\40721\Desktop\nodeJs&Express\complete-node-bootcamp-master\1-node-farm\index.js:49:38)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:257:13)

The data.json file i want to read from is this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "productName": "Fresh Avocados",
    "image": "",
    "from": "Spain",
    "nutrients": "Vitamin B, Vitamin K",
    "quantity": "4 ",
    "price": "6.50",
    "organic": true,
    "description": "A ripe avocado yields to gentle pressure when held in the palm of the hand and squeezed. The fruit is not sweet, but distinctly and subtly flavored, with smooth texture. The avocado is popular in vegetarian cuisine as a substitute for meats in sandwiches and salads because of its high fat content. Generally, avocado is served raw, though some cultivars, including the common 'Hass', can be cooked for a short time without becoming bitter. It is used as the base for the Mexican dip known as guacamole, as well as a spread on corn tortillas or toast, served with spices."
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "productName": "Goat and Sheep Cheese",
    "image": "",
    "from": "Portugal",
    "nutrients": "Vitamin A, Calcium",
    "quantity": "250g",
    "price": "5.00",
    "organic": false,
    "description": "Creamy and distinct in flavor, goat cheese is a dairy product enjoyed around the world. Goat cheese comes in a wide variety of flavors and textures, from soft and spreadable fresh cheese to salty, crumbly aged cheese. Although it’s made using the same coagulation and separation process as cheese made from cow’s milk, goat cheese differs in nutrient content."
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "productName": "Apollo Broccoli",
    "image": "",
    "from": "Portugal",
    "nutrients": "Vitamin C, Vitamin K",
    "quantity": "3 ",
    "price": "5.50",
    "organic": true,
    "description": "Broccoli is known to be a hearty and tasty vegetable which is rich in dozens of nutrients. It is said to pack the most nutritional punch of any vegetable. When we think about green vegetables to include in our diet, broccoli is one of the foremost veggies to come to our mind. Broccoli is a cruciferous vegetable and part of the cabbage family, which includes vegetables such as Brussel sprouts and kale. Although the tastes are different, broccoli and these other vegetables are from the same family."
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "productName": "Baby Carrots",
    "image": "",
    "from": "France",
    "nutrients": "Vitamin A, Vitamin K",
    "quantity": "20 ",
    "price": "3.00",
    "organic": true,
    "description": "The carrot is a root vegetable that is often claimed to be the perfect health food. It is crunchy, tasty and highly nutritious. Carrots are a particularly good source of beta-carotene, fiber, vitamin K, potassium and antioxidants. Carrots have a number of health benefits. They are a weight loss friendly food and have been linked to lower cholesterol levels and improved eye health."
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "productName": "Sweet Corncobs",
    "image": "",
    "from": "Germany",
    "nutrients": "Vitamin C, Magnesium",
    "quantity": "2 ",
    "price": "2.00",
    "organic": false,
    "description": "Also known as maize, corn is one of the most popular cereal grains in the world. Popcorn and sweet corn are commonly eaten varieties, but refined corn products are also widely consumed, frequently as ingredients in foods. These include tortillas, tortilla chips, polenta, cornmeal, corn flour, corn syrup, and corn oil. Whole-grain corn is as healthy as any cereal grain, rich in fiber and many vitamins, minerals, and antioxidants."
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you used `body-parser`?

Comment: Side note, you are going to want to remove `res.end('Hello from the server!');`

Comment: I didn't. I have read the input text from a json file, I don't think i need a body parser (i don't req anything)

Comment: @BogdanDoncea you don't need "body.parse".
What do you get if you put a console.log(data) before "const productData = JSON.parse(data);"?

Comment: oh, i have found my mistake. I have written "response.writeHead()..." instead of "res" (how i declared it)... i spent a really lot of time seeing this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Nice one. I did the same course a few months ago and it is great. You will learn a lot. ;)

Comment: @LucasL. yea, the teacher is pretty great, I really like his style. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Are you storing the image property as a location to the image? JSON only accepts these datatypes:

```
 a string
    a number
    an object (JSON object)
    an array
    a boolean
    null
```

Comment: the image property is still a String, not a real image

Comment: @connor : It is not image. It is Character just like alphabets and numbers.

Comment: Care to explain? I always have been told to store the location to an image and grab it via the JSON EDIT: Just saw the reply, that makes more sense, my apologies, I assumed it was an image

Comment: @ChiefKeith a good and quick read about data/emojis:
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/notes/0/ - Section: Representing data

Comment: Thank you Lucas!